# Issue with mac os upgrade

Tags: c++, python-2.7, go, clang, apple-silicon

I updated my mac os to ventura. I found out that python2 is removed from that.So I have installed which is needed for my project.In my project we are using golang and python2. After upgrading whenever I try to start my golang project I am getting below error

> /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit

> status 1 ld: warning: directory not found for option

> '-L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib'

> ld:library not found for -lpython2.7 clang: error: linker command failed

> with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have also updated my pythonpath and in new upgrade the pythonpath is not here

*/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib* Instead it is like the below

*/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib*

go lang - 1.18

python - 2.7.16

I am facing this issue only after this os upgrade. can someone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use  [conda (or miniconda)](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html)   to create a local environment and then install the specific packages you need to use for your program. Much better than trying to install outdated packages to your root system.

Comment: Hey @pds I have used pyenv to install